# double free or corruption when using object instead of pointer

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, destructor

Why does the first code snippet result in a double free or corruption error when calling the destructor, while the second snippet works fine?

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
vector<int> vec = *new vector<int>(10);
vec.at(3) = 6;
vec.~vector(); 
}
```

This one works:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>(10);
vec->at(3) = 6;
vec->~vector();
}
```

And even if the destructor is called two times: Why does the error appear in the second last line(according to gbd) and not at `}` when the object passes out of scope?

Comment: In the first case, vec has automatic duration so gets deleted twice. BTW, you should NOT call the destructor that way, but through the `delete` operator

Comment: But why is that? The only difference I can see is that I'm storing the object instead of the pointer. I thought everything created with `new` has to be deleted manually.

Comment: In the first case, `vec` is an *object* with automatic duration, while in the second case `vec` is a *pointer* to an object, which does *not* get freed upon exit.

Comment: Think of what should happen with `vector<int> vec = new vector<int>(10); vector<int> *p_vec = &vec;`. The object will *not* be freed twice in this scenario, because the pointer doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yes, you are also leaking memory, in fact. In the first line of main, you create a vector on the heap and copy it into a vector on the stack. The heap one will never be destroyed, the stack one gets destroyed twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine the code line by line. Program one:

```
vector<int> vec = *new vector<int>(10);
```

A vector vec is defined left of the `=`. Another, unnamed vector is created right of the `=` on the heap. Note that this involves two free store allocations: One for the (small) vector object proper, and a second one for the data in it, 10 ints. The address returned by `new` is not preserved anywhere, but is dereferenced immediately so that the expression to the right of `=` is a vector object. It is used to copy-initialize vec. This involves allocating memory for vec's data on the free store and copying all of the anonymous vector's elements into it. Note that vec's data is in a different location from the right hand side vector's data.

`vec.at(3) = 6;`: Irrelevant for the discussion.

`vec.~vector();`: Executing vec's destructor will free the memory allocated for data on the free store when vec was initialized. It will not attempt to free vec's memory (which is good because vec is not on the heap but on the stack and will be destroyed automatically when the stack is unwound because the scope is left).

`}`:  The scope of vec ends so that vec's destructor is called again (the language does not keep book of destruction, for example there is no "destroyed" flag in objects). This is a bad thing because, as we know, `~vector()` tries to free the memory allocated for its data. (It's debatable whether it should also set the data pointer to null in which case multiple de-allocation attempts would not be catastrophic. The counter argument is that that would only mask catastrophic programming errors.)

Apart from the obvious double de-allocation of vec's data due to the erroneous explicit destructor call it's also important that the vector on the free store which was used for vec's initialization is never freed nor destroyed. (It cannot be freed since the address is lost.) That is ok for vectors of PODs in a fully-featured runtime environment: The POD elements do not need destruction, and the runtime returns a process's  heap to the OS when the process exits. But the hints are obvious: What if the elements require destruction (think database connections which now are never closed); and there are standalone implementations where the memory may not be returned to the OS (which OS?), or the code gets used as part of a long-running server without reconsideration.

Program two:

```
std::vector<int> *vec = new std::vector<int>(10);
```

This line defines a *pointer* vec on the left side of `=`. The right side creates a vector of ints on the free store. The address of that unnamed vector is used to initialize the pointer vec. Note that, as in the first example, two allocations on the free store are involved in the call to `new`: The (small) memory for the vector proper, and the (separate, large) memory for the data the vector "contains".

`vec->at(3) = 6;` is irrelevant to the discussion.

`vec->~vector();` explicitly calls vec's destructor. This frees the vector's data but leaves the vector proper untouched. The latter is bad because the vector object to which `vec` points was allocated on the free store and should be freed as well. The proper way to do both at the same time is calling `delete` as suggested by another answer. (But the discussion above applies -- in a normal runtime it doesn't matter for an int vector if the program ends anyway).

`}`: The scope of the pointer `vec` ends, which doesn't trigger anything (in particular, it doesn't free the memory `vec` points to, which is bad here, and it doesn't call the vector's destructor, which is good here). Note that smart pointers would behave differently and potentialy call delete on the raw pointers they hold internally when their scope ends.

Comment: Well, this really settles all my questions about this topic. I accept the answer,though others also provided nice explanations.

Answer (score 2):

This `vector<int> vec = *new vector<int>(10);` actually creates two vectors. The first one is created by `new vector<int>(10)`. Then a second one, `vec`, is created using the copy constructor.
The first one is never destroyed. The second is destroyed twice, by manually calling the destructor and automatically when it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

**First case:**

```
vector<int> vec = *new vector<int>(10);
```

Here three things happen:

1. You dynamically allocate a vector. `new` returns a pointer. In this case it is a temporary variable, which does not have a name.
2. You dereference this pointer and get an *rvalue*.
3. You construct another object, `vec`, initialising it with the rvalue from the previous step. This effectively calls a copy-constructor `vector(const vector&)`.

As a result, there are two vectors. The first one is somewhere in the heap, and you do not have a pointer to it. This is a *memory leak*. Then, there is an *automatic duration* object `vec`. Both vectors have equal content.

```
vec.~vector();
```

Here you explicitly call a descructor of an automatic duration object. You almost never need to do it. This is mainly intended to be used for implementing *placement new*.

As soon as you leave the scope (e.g. leave the function body), the destructor is automatically called once more. Hence, you get a double-free error.

**Second case:**

```
vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>(10);
vec->~vector();
```

Here you destroy the object (i.e. call the destructor), but do not free the memory it occupied. Thus, you still have a memory leak. But, as dynamic objects are not automatically destroyed when we leave the scope, no double-free errors occur.

You should use `delete vec;` to destroy the dynamically allocated vector. It will call the destructor and free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions contain errors but the first is really bad here is how it should look if you decide to use a vector object:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(10);
    vec.at(3) = 6;
}
```

And this is how it could look using the pointer:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::vector<int> *vec = new std::vector<int>(10);
    vec->at(3) = 6;
    delete vec;
}
```

last line is not even necessary as the program will terminate and ram will be free in anycase.

Comment: Every `new` should be paired with a `delete` as a matter of good form and practice (but modern C++ should remove many of the cases where direct memory allocation is needed).